# How to prevent a a null value as the new value for ValueChangedEvent?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Inside an input type field I have a value binding to a variable(lets call `foo`) of type `double` for the `value` property in my jsp . I have a setter and a getter for `foo` and there is also a `ValueChangedListener` registered for this input . The `autosubmit` attribute of that field is set to true . When the user clears the input and navigates to the next field ,the code inside `valueChangedListener` gets invoked and the `newValue` of the `ValueChangedEvent` is coming null . How can I prevent this ?

I tried handling this from the setter method but it seems the setter is not getting called and the `valueChangedListener` is getting called first . Doesn't the spec say that setter should be called first to populate the user edited value to the component and then only the ValueChangedListener gets fired ?

P.S: I am using ADF RichInputText as the input but I think it is not related to ADF but to core JSF machinery. Hence not tagging it as ADF question.

Comment: What's the functional requirement? Why do you want to prevent this? That's fully expected behavior. As to the invocation order, that's also fully as per specification. Note that a `valueChangeListener` may actually be the wrong tool for the actual job if you're not interested in `getOldValue()`.

Comment: @BalusC I need to validate the new value and I am not interested in the old value . Also why the setter won't be called before the <code>valueChangeListener</code> ?What other options do I have ?

Comment: Validate the value? Why don't you use a normal `Validator`? As to the invocation order, why should it be? Once the setter is invoked, the old value is not available anymore and this defeats the actual purpose of the value change listener.

Comment: @Balusc so you are suggesting to provide a null check in the validator ? there is now way i can prevent a null value and if the users clears out the value , send 0.0 to the server instead of a null ?

Comment: @Balusc Will the validator run before the valueChangedListener ? i guess only when validation passes , it should invoke a ValueChangedEvent , right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I need to validate the new value and I am not interested in the old value.*

A `valueChangeListener` is then the wrong tool for the job. Use a normal `Validator`. In order to validate empty but required fields, use `required="true"`. In order to skip custom validators on empty fields, add the following context param to `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The only disadvantage is that this will also skip `@NotNull`/`@NotBlank` JSR303 bean validation, but that shouldn't harm if you aren't using it anyway.

---

> *Also why the setter won't be called before the `valueChangeListener`?*

Because the old value is otherwise lost and this would defeat the purpose of the value change listener.

---

> *Will the validator run before the valueChangedListener ? I guess only when validation passes , it should invoke a ValueChangedEvent , right ?*

That's correct. The value change listener is only invoked when the component has passed validation (i.e. `UIInput#isValid()` returns `true`). Noted should be again that when you're not interested in the old value, the value change listener is most likely the wrong tool for the job you had in mind.